# How to fetch data getting in console to HTML in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data in ts, i need to fetch that data inside the Angular4 html, but i am able to fetch only 2 data which are outside the loop. Can anyone help me to fetch data inside angular4.

HTML:

```
              <tr *ngFor="let accept of accepts">
                <td>{{accept.name}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.description}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.daterecv}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.dateacc}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.deadline}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.price}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.status}}</td>
                <td>{{accept.due_date}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Ts:

```
this.service
            .getProfileData(id)
            .subscribe(
              data => {
                this.accepts = data;
                console.log(this.accepts);
              }, error => {})
```

Consoled Output:

[image]

Comment: Seems you given wrong object keys inside the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the fields rendered are wrong,make sure the keys are present in the data in the ts also use safe navigation operator to make sure data is present, it should be as

```
<tr *ngFor="let accept of accepts">
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.User?.name}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.user?.description}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.price}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.status}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.due_date}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am getting error as "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: sorry, i am not getting description in that td

Comment: can date format be changed? instead of 2019-03-01T16:32:30.239Z, can i get 01-03-2019 or viceversa?

Comment: ya i will try that, can that description be brought into html?

Comment: yes it should be just    <td>{{accept?.user?.description}}</td>

Comment: ya ya sorry it has come, i havent seen..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
 <tr *ngFor="let accept of accepts">
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.User?.name}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.description}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.deadline}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.price}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.status}}</td>
            <td>{{accept?.Job?.due_date}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, trying

Comment: can date format be changed? instead of 2019-03-01T16:32:30.239Z, can i get 01-03-2019 or viceversa?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Yes you can use momentjs for any type of conversion. I have tried momentjs

Comment: ya i will try to do that

Comment: Can you please help me how to tackle date with moment.. i have tried for calender's but not getting to do with data cmng from backend